# returning value using closures in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

While trying to understand closures in JS,I came across the following code:

```
  var add = function () {      
    var name = "xyz";
    return function ()
      {
        return name;            
      }          
  }
  ();
```

I am unable to understand the purpose of **()** at the end of the function.

Using `console.log(add());` gives `xyz` as the output.

But when I remove the **()** from the end of the function, I am getting `[Function]` as the output.

Comment: is the normal sitax declaration for a function ..

Comment: it's the normal syntax for a function call

Comment: it is a javascript self invoking anonymous functions http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: If `function f(){}` is a function definition and `f()` is a function call, then `function f(){}()` is the same function call with inlining the function definition (simply substitute`f` with the definition).